# Calling a Dynamic String from one class to another

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine

I am new to C# and i tried to call a string variable from one class to another.

It works fine. But the string called is the one which i assigned it as public at the top.

In runtime the string changes and i can't get that string variable which is dynamic. Please help me in getting the dynamic string value from one class to another.

Comment: Paste your code. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: do you mean you want to copy string in class1 to string in class2 by reference?

Comment: Yeah, Exactly i expect the same.

Answer (score 0):

Right, so presuming you have two classes.

```
class class1 {
    public string string1;
    //code for class1
}
class class2 {
    class1 c1 = new class1();
    string string1 = c1.string1;
}
```

The first class contains the public string, and the second class contains the access to the public string. However, when we add a method into the second class that calls the string, it will call the string as it was when the class was initialised.

To make the method call the latest version of the string use this:

```
    class class1 {
    public string string1;
    //code for class1
}
class class2 {
    class1 c1 = new class1();
    public void method1 {
        var string1 = c1.string1;
    }
}
```

I believe that will fix your issue, comment if it doesn't help.

References: Experience, MDSN

Answer (score 0):

you can make the string value as a property and then call it as follows

```
class class1 {
    public string string1{ set; get; }
    //code for class1
}
class class2 {
    class1 c1 = new class1();
    //then you can call it like this
    string test = c1.string1;
}
```